# Unix - Find and printf only part of filename

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

I have this command:

```
find <path> -mindepth 2 -type f -name '*_????????????.csv' -printf '\n%AD %AT %p' | sort -b -nr | cut -c 30-
```

Result:

```
Date, Time and Path
```

But I need to print what's in the `?` (between `_` and `.csv`).

Comment: but there's no parentheses in your command.

Comment: @bigeast, my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say your folder structure looks like this :

```
ubuntu#  find ./  -type f -name '*.csv'
./file_12345.csv
./subfolder/moremore_hahahaha.csv
./45468_somefile.csv
```

In this case this will do :

```
find ./  -type f -name '*.csv' -exec basename {} \; | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $2}'
```

Result :

```
12345
hahahaha
somefile
```

EDIT as per OP's comment :

```
find ./  -type f -name '*.csv'  -printf '\n%AD %AT %p' | awk '{ $4 = $3 ; sub(/[.]csv/,"",$3) ;sub(/.*_/," ",$3) ; print $1 " " $2 " " $4 " " $3}'
```

Regards!

Comment: I want keep "\n%AD %AT %p"

Result: Datetime, Path, (part of filename between _ and .)